# MySQL: Unable to Generate dynamic order number

Tags: mysql

I can't generate order numbers using sub query.
here i some sample code which has few tables join.
i need to get order number from this query only.

I got correct result but some of the other join tables got Recline(order) is got null after changing the `BookHeadId`.

```
select @rhBookHeadId :=rh.BookHeadId ,rd.BookDetailId,@inrec:=0,(select RecLine from (SELECT spodno.BookDetailId, @inrec:= ifnull(@inrec,0)+1, @inrec as RecLine FROM tblBookDetail spodno where spodno.BookHeadId=@rhBookHeadId and spodno.isActive=1 order by spodno.BookDetailId asc ) temp where temp.BookDetailId=rd.BookDetailId) as RecLine from  tblBookHead rh inner join tblBookDetail rh on rh.BookHeadId=rd.BookHeadId inner join ......;
```

Comment: Queries are great, but sometimes they're not the best way to communicate a problem.

Comment: @Strawberry do you know any solution for this.

Comment: Any solution for what?

Comment: i got RecLine first time correct after changed headid then it goes to null

response:
rhBookHeadId  RecLine 
65   1
65   2
65   3
66   null

Comment: I doubt that anyone reading this would have any idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

i got answer by using functions in mysql.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`mycura`@`%` FUNCTION `getRecLine`(dBookDetailId bigint(20),
dBookHeadId bigint(20)
) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
declare dRecLine int default 0;

set @inrec =0;

select RecLine into dRecLine from (
SELECT spodno.BookDetailId, @inrec:= @inrec+1, @inrec as RecLine 
FROM tblBookDetail spodno where spodno.BookHeadId=dBookHeadId and spodno.isActive=1 order by 
spodno.BookDetailId asc ) temp
where temp.BookDetailId=dBookDetailId;



RETURN dRecLine;
END $$
```

then called that function . it works

```
select getRecLine(rd.BookDetailId,rh.BookHeadId) as  RecLine from  tblBookHead rh inner join tblBookDetail rh on rh.BookHeadId=rd.BookHeadId inner join ......;
```